# como agregarle una manejador de evento click a mi clase userChat creada desde javascript

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, websocket

he creado con javascript una clase llamada userChat quisiera poderle agregar a la clase userChat un manejador de evento click para que cuando presione click en userChat me mande el nombre del usuario al que le estoy dando click el problema es que le agregue un addEventListener pero no me funciona no se que estoy haciendo mal me podrían ayudar por favor muchas gracias

```
    function updateUsers(socket){   
    socket.on('updateUsers',function(data){       
        let usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
        usuarios.innerHTML='';
        for(let i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
            let us = `<div class ="userChat">` +data.users[i] +`</div>`;
            usuarios.innerHTML += us;
            

            let userchat = document.querySelector('.userChat');
            userchat.addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('estas tocando al usuario: '+data.users[i]);
            });
        }       
    });
    }
```

Comment: Ese código se está ejecutando en el navegador o en node?

Comment: es de la parte del cliente del navegador

Comment: ¿Cuántos elementos tienes con clase "userChat", solo uno?, si son más, deberías usar `querySelectorAll()` y recorrer para asignar a cada uno el evento.

Comment: si solo tengo 1

Comment: pero no funciona asi

Comment: @JhonOneall Si sólo tuvieses un elemento, no necesitarías el bucle for, deben estar añadiéndose más de un elemento a menos que sólo tengas un usuario siempre

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar

```
userchat.addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log('estas tocando al usuario: '+data.users[i]);
});
```

por:

```
userchat.on('click',function(){
    console.log('estas tocando al usuario: '+data.users[i]);
});
```

o si no puedes importar jquery y directamente hacer:

```
$('.userChat').click(function(){});
```

Comment: no estoy usando jquery

Comment: Prueba a usar el evento .on

Comment: ya lo intente no funciona

Comment: que error te da??

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: userchat is not defined este

Comment: No veo nada raro, ese es todo el código?? si no prueba a poner:

document.querySelector('.userChat').addEventListener('click', function(){});

Comment: hice eso también y tampoco me funciona puedes crear tu un ejemplo claro sin express ni socket.io solo javascript a ver que puedo hacer